# How do I reference a specific index of element in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Let's say I initialize an `ArrayList` using the following code:

```
 ArrayList fib = new ArrayList();

    fib.add(18);
    fib.add(23);
    fib.add(37);
    fib.add(45);
    fib.add(50);
    fib.add(67);
    fib.add(38);
    fib.add(88);
    fib.add(91);
    fib.add(10);
```

What if I want to reference a specific index of the array. I don't want what's in the index. I want the index itself. I know this seems redundant, but it spills into another code.

To reference what's IN the index, I would do this:

```
 fib.temp(4);
```

and it would yield

```
50
```

What if I want what index it is?

Comment: Given the fact that `List` is 0 indexed, wouldn't it return `50`...?

Comment: Your question is very inconsistent, using `temp` and `fib` almost interchangably - and then referring to your list as an array, which it certainly isn't... A lot of the discipline of software engineering is paying attention to the details. Please take more care in your next question.

Comment: You are mixing up `ArrayList` with `Array`, what you want, `Array` can do that for you...

Comment: `fib.get(3)`, where `4` is a 0 based index, returns 45

Comment: Apologies, everyone. This question was posted in a rush. I'm usually very considerate of my writing. Thank you for your edits, answers, and comments.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you're looking for [`List.indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
int index = fib.indexOf(45); // index is now 3
```

`indexOf` returns -1 if the value isn't found in the list.

Note that `temp` *isn't* a member of `ArrayList`, and if you use `fib.get(4)` it will return 50, not 45 - because the index is 0-based, not 1-based.

Comment: So it would be temp.indexOf(4)?

And that would return...4?

Comment: @priya No, it would return `-1` based on the example.  `temp.indexOf(50)` would return `4`...

Comment: @priya: No, it would be `temp.indexOf(45)`. Or maybe `fib.indexOf(45)` - the naming in your question is inconsistent. Either way, that would return 3.

Comment: @JonSkeet That makes sense. I feel foolish for forgetting counting starts at 0. Thanks.

Comment: And yes - I mixed up the ArrayList names. It should be:

    ArrayList fib = new ArrayList();